# Submitting a Form using Jquery

Tags: forms, jquery, submit

Okay so I am converting some code to jQuery and currently the js is just changing the focus to a button with the target id using whenever you press enter or double click in a `<select>` tag. `document.getElementById.focus()` and then `document.getElementById.click()` and returning true to submit this form. Just looking for some example on how to do same thing using jQuery instead. I understand that there is a `.keypress()` and a `.dblclick()` function in jQuery and thats what I think I should be using but passing the values of the input box or the select values are a little difficult since there are multiples of each in the form. FYI this is a search page that sends SQL to an oracle database.
Update-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
       $(this).keypress() 
        if(event.which ==13){   
        }
    });
});
```

This is what i have so far not sure if i am on the right track or not.
so here is an example of how the form is.

```
<form>
 <tr>
    <td nowrap="nowrap"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search by Number&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top"><input type="text" name="revisor_number"     value=revisor_number>" size="55" maxlength="100" /><br/><span style="font-size:75%">commas between numbers (10,15,20), dash for range(10-20)</span><br/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit_number" id="submit_number" value="GO"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td style="vertical-align:top" nowrap="nowrap"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search by Type&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
<td>
    <select name="subtype[]" size="3" multiple="multiple" onkeypress="keyPress(event, 'submit_subtype');" ondblclick="keyPress(event, 'submit_subtype');">
    <option value="">>--- All ---</option>
  <td style="vertical-align:top">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="submit_subtype" id="submit_subtype" value="GO"/></td>
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and then we might be able to help

Comment: I basically want to have a form submitted when enter is pressed or when a double click occurs in a select tag on a form.

Comment: You need to execute the form submit when the keypress event happens or the double click happens. It looks like you are submitting the form first.

Comment: yeah i was just writing away and had not changed it around yet. still pretty new to jquery.

Comment: The HTML you're working with is... a total mess. My first suggestion would be to clean that up quite a lot as you've got some serious markup issues.

Comment: I actually deleted a lot of the php code that was thrown in there but our whole html is like that for our form on this page. I will bring up with the other developers. we are planning on completely changing our whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move it outside of your submit function, replace it with:

```
$('input, textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $(this).blur();
    $('#submit').focus().click();
    }
});
```

Assuming '#submit' is the ID of your button.

Comment: yeah that might actually work. the only problem is that there are multiple buttons with each one having a different id and send a different value to the php page that makes the sql statements. Thats where my biggest problem has been. trying to make sure that its that button that is clicked and not the other ones. Each select and input elements are in there own <tr> tag.

Comment: You could maybe use .closest() jQuery function to get the submit button you want to trigger the event on?

Comment: Yeah i am going try that. didn't know there was a function like that. seems pretty uselful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand what you want,

but submitting a form with a button in jQuery is something like :

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('yourForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Close i want the form to be submitted when enter key is pressed or when a select value is selected and double clicked.